# Angular 2 Materialize DatePicker

Tags: angularjs-2.0, materialize

Tengo un datepicker de materialize en Angular 2 y no consigo obtener el modelo del input

**component.html**

```
<form name="assignPeriodo_form" (ngSubmit)="assign_periodo()" >
   <div class="col m6">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i>
      <label for="expires">Fecha Fin</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="model.expires" id="expires" name="expires" type="date" class="datepicker" required>
   </div>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
assign_periodo(){
        console.log(this.model.expires);
}
```

Recibo `undefined` todo el rato.

He visto temas parecidos con el de bs como el link pero no funciona de la misma manera
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087762/how-to-detect-bootstrap-datetimepicker-change-events-within-angular2

Answer (score 1):

En la mayoría de los casos el *undefined*, te lo mostrará porque no has añadido datos a dicha variable. Asegúrate que has *inicializado* la variable, y que lo has hecho en el lugar correcto. Si usas el Visual Code, te puede ayudar mucho.

Un ejemplo de Angular: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/forms/ts/eplnkr.html

Por si necesitases algún ejemplo más concreto, indico algo probado en local por mí, el fragmento necesario:

Archivo: fecha.component.js

```js
model: Date;

assign_periodo(): void {
      console.log(this.model);
}
```

El fichero html:

```html
<form name="assignPeriodo_form">
   <div class="col m6">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i>
      <label for="model">Fecha Fin</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="model" id="model" name="model" type="date" class="datepicker">
   </div>
</form>

<button (click)="assign_periodo()">Ver datos</button>
```